# On F11/Fullscreen mode YouTube IFrame zooms in really far, as a result making the video quality worse

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube-iframe-api

I used the same code as this website called [Virtual Vacation](https://virtualvacation.us/guess)
so as a result they have the same issue as me. I'm thinking of reaching out to them and notifying of this but I can't figure out any way to fix it..

**Specifically on WINDOWS 10,** When you load a video, and then go into F11/Fullscreen mode, the video zooms in like 20-30%. It works on other OS like MacOS and ChromeOS, but on Windows it does that.. Here is the source code: [SC](http://view-source:https://virtualvacation.us/guess)

I have included a video with all the necessary needed like browsers, latest updates, and the steps I took to replicate the issue.

Please take a look at the video: [here](https://vimeo.com/user125246603/review/469168513/fb818b5c25).. it displays all the problems.

**End question:** Explanation or code example to prevent the zooming in on F11.

[Video Of Issue](https://vimeo.com/user125246603/review/469168513/fb818b5c25)

[Image of Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLdlJ.jpg)

Comment: Also this is my first post lol

Comment: `Here is the source code`, bad link, when fixed, shows over 2000 lines of code! that's not minimal - `Please take a look at the video` - bad link, `Video Of Issue` bad link - anyway - perhaps the video is low resolution, so zooming it will make it look bad regardless

Comment: wow that site is addictive!! anyway, never had a problem with any videos at virtual vacation in fullscreen mode on windows 10 in firefox - perhaps your videos are bad quality

Comment: If you go into the full screen (f11) when playing the video, it zooms in. Are you using windows 10 chrome? (firefox works)

Comment: No, I don't use chrome for many reasons, and yes, I see what you mean - why is chrome the most popular browser is a mystery, this, and every other release breaking multiple sites makes it the crappiest browser you can use - really the video is already pretty crap compared with firefox even before going full screen in chrome/edge

Comment: Hi Jaromanda, I don't know if your able to help me, but I'm still trying to fix this problem.

Comment: Any idea's on how I could fix it? Do you think its something with YouTube? It seems as if when I go into fullscreen, and open inspect element, it goes back to normal.. but when I close inspect element, the issue occurs again. It seems to be something with the screen resolution?

Comment: It's alright if your not sure @Jaromanda X, just grasping at whatever I can get here.. lol

Comment: well, the problem exists with chrome and chrome based edge - I think the problem is with the browser

Comment: @JaromandaX Hey there, still working on this issue. Your right, it's likely something to do with the browser. Is there any way that I can detect F11 mode and stop it from making changes related the page, but still allow the mode from happening? Thanks!

Comment: not sure, but as I said, the video looks bad in chrome without going to full screen mode - I'd be looking into different video formats to see which ones chrome can handle properly

Comment: OK #1 your vimeo link is down #2 I can't reproduce your problem on my 22 inch screen neither on my other bigger screen desktop on WIN 10 PRO Latest version + Chrome latest version stable. Can you provide another video link so I can try to help you thanks? videos look fine to me really i tried 4-5 different ones

Comment: also z-index 900000000000000000000000000 might be a little overkill just saying. and why is the JS inlined?

Comment: @DenzelGrover you can intercept F11 if you want to with the `keyup` event and event.preventDefault(). Here is the documentation for `keyup` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event

Answer (score 0):

This just may be a problem with your os. Try getting a full screen app or extension. That may help with the problem. Sincere @shed